# qgis2web not displaying some layers

Tags: qgis2web

I'm working on a school project for property management and want to create an interactive web map. Everything was going well in QGIS until I encountered issues with the qgis2web plugin. [image]

After updating the preview in the plugin dialog box, the 'Buildings' and 'Boundary' layers were not displayed. [image]

I checked the 'Appearance' settings, but none of the adjustments and filtering I made were reflected in the preview.[image]

Went ahead to export and the only thing I could see is a boring and non-interactive map [image]

Comment: Beware adding statements of urgency to your Questions. Sometimes it will generate downvotes, and usually it will result in extra delay in response. If you're not paying for it, you can't assert urgency and get a positive outcome.

Comment: Have you tried to export the map with openlayers?  from what I see the project seems configured well, did you follow this guide? https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html If you want I can check your data if you publish it and provide a link.  It will be far from boring, I assure you, check out this demo https://www.opengis.it/demo/ created with qgis2web and then integrated.

Comment: Yes i have exported and meticulously follow the guide alongside a video tutorial. please i will appreciate if you can help me look into it  https://pizzletech.github.io/Property_management/ 
and that demo is mind blowing

Comment: Hi Andrea thanks so much for offering to help, i've figured it out, thanks once again

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem yourself, it would be helpful if you write how you solved it, also as an answer to your own question, so you will help others with the same problem as you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all layers must have the CRS assigned, and it may be necessary to select the "Match project CRS" option not the "Apperance" tab.
I did this in a similar situation and it worked.